# Error during TFS 2012 reporting configuration

Tags: sql-server, tfs, report, reporting

I have `TFS2012` installed. It was migrated from `TFS 2010` and that was migrated from `TFS 2005`, we moved DB server several times and at some point we've lost Reporting and `Sharepoint`. It didn't worked properly and we anyway didn't use it.

Now we are trying to setup reporting again. I open Administration Console and go to Application Tir\Repoting. I have sql server s0sql01 with instance called ittfs11. That instance contains TFS databases and also has reporting an danalysuis services installed.

I edit Reporting Services, enable "Use Reporting" check-box and start fill settings. On tabs Warehouse and Analysis sservices I enter server adress and instance name, I enter new DB name and "Test connection" shows that everything is fine.

But when I try to set `s0sql01\ittfs11` server on `"Reports" tab` and press `"Populate URLs" button` - I get this:

```
TF255186: The following SQL Repoting Services Instance could not be found: ittfs11. The server name is: s0sql01.
```

My user and TFS user are full admins in SQL Server on that instance. I do not use Sharepoint mode.
What should I do to fix problem?

Comment: Is Reporting configured, and in Native mode?

Comment: Yes, reporting services are configured in Native mode. I can access Web Interface of reporting as well as interface through Mangement Studio.

Comment: You can enable TFS Admin Console logging. Set to 4 the Registry Key TraceLevel located under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\11.0\Admin, launch DbgView, then restart the Console and retry.